# Error: C++ preprocessor failed sanity check

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, raspberry-pi

I am trying to compile libmad for my Raspberry Pi which is using the new Pidora builds which use the armv6hl architecture.

When I try to compile libmad using gcc I end up with the error:

```
Error: C++ preprocessor failed sanity check
```

The config.log is here: http://pastebin.com/Y1vgWgQN

Hopefully someone can help me resolve this, or knows of a compiled version of libmad for armv6hl

Comment: "*The following error will be displayed if no C++ preprocessor is found installed on the system.*"

Comment: isnt gcc both a C and C++ compiler? or do i need to install a separate C++ preporcessor

Comment: [How to fix](http://www.asteriskdocs.org/en/2nd_Edition/asterisk-book-html-chunk/asterisk-CHP-3-SECT-8.html)

Comment: The preprocessor is `cpp` not `gcc`. Now I don't know much about Fedora/Pidora's package management so I can't really help you further. Fact is, `configure` doesn't find `cpp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C++ preprocessor was not found, probably because the preprocessor is `gcc` not `cpp`.

Answer (score 3):

Was in the end due to cpp not being installed (thanks to everyone for pointing this out), I fixed this by installing the package gcc-c++ i.e

```
yum install gcc-c++
```